# Django - AJAX POST causes broken pipe

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I know Broken pipe is caused because of clashing requests so the POST doesn't get any time to process.

Here I'm sending these two requests:

1. Ajax Post
2. redirect to /message.html

So the event.preventDefault() might fix this. But, when I add the preventDefault() option, I'am not receiving the POST request at all.
And adding a timeout will be a very poor fix to this since it'll halt at every request.

Error im getting is :

```
[13/Apr/2016 10:36:38]"POST /secreturl HTTP/1.1" 500 12202
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 51133)
```

my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type= 'text/css'>
    <link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<script type = "text/javascript" 
  src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked(){
        //alert("Coming inside clicked!");
        ValidateEmail();
    }
    function ValidateEmail(){  
        //ValidateEmail.preventDefault();
        if(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(document.getElementById("validate-text").value)){
            //alert("correct email!");  
            // do a post request to insert into db
            var email = document.getElementById("validate-text").value
            var datz = {
                "email" : email,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}'
            }

            $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/secreturl',
                type: "POST",
                data: datz,
                success: function (result) {
                    //alert('startline posted');
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 //alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
                }
            });
            return (true);

        }else{  
            alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");  
            return (false);
        } 
    } 
</script>

<body>
    <div class="site-wrapper">
        <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
            <div class="cover-container">
                <div class="center-block col-md-7">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 padding0">
                            <img src="{% static 'img/CowsCrop.png' %}" width="90%">
                            <div class="image-caption">Her 'Achhe din' are definitely here. What about yours?</div>
                            <img src="{% static 'img/mobile.png' %}" width="70%" class="padding2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control flat-form" name="validate-text" id="validate-text" placeholder="Leave your e-mail & be the 1st one to know when the awesomeness is out!" required>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon danger flat-form button-color">
                                        <!-- <a href="message.html" onclick="clicked()">I WANT IT!</a> -->
                                        <a href="/message" onclick="return ValidateEmail();">Want It!</a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right padding1">
                            <img src="{% static 'img/facebook.png' %}" width="32px" height="32px">
                            <img src="{% static 'img/twitter.png' %}" width="32px" height="32px">
                            <img src="{% static 'img/instagram.png' %}" width="32px" height="32px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"   integrity="sha256-36cp2Co+/62rEAAYHLmRCPIych47CvdM+uTBJwSzWjI="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

And one more thing i'd like to add, I'm also not able to send the csrf_token since I'm going to JSON.stringify(data) django is unable to extract the csrf_token out of it, and also I'm not using any forms so won't be able to use :

```
<form></form> {% csrf_token %}
```

Server side :

```
//views.py
def home(request):
    print "Request has been received"
    print request
    context = {
        'MEDIA_ROOT' : "//home//mayur//Documents//Gigit//Gigit//Gigit//static//images//",
        'MEDIA_URL' : 'http://localhost:8000/static/',
    }
    return render(request, "index2.html", context)

def test(request):
    print "POST works"
    #return render(request,"", {})

def message(request):
    print " message request received"
    return render(request, "message.html", {})

def insertQuery(request):
    print "Insert query received"
    # resp = json.loads(request)
    # print resp
    print request

//models.py
class visitors(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
quesId = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
answer = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
notify = models.BooleanField(default = True)
regTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

//urls.py
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', 'questionAnswer.views.home'),
url(r'^test/', 'questionAnswer.views.test'),
url(r'^message', 'questionAnswer.views.message'),
url(r'^secreturl', 'questionAnswer.views.insertQuery'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: @Koterpillar I dont think the server code will help

Comment: Broken pipe is when a request is getting cancelled by a client in the middle. When a browser navigates away to /messages it aborts your ajax call. You either need to wait for the ajax call to complete before doing redirect, or pass your ajax parameters right to the messages url and process them in your messages view (can add another intermediate page in front that checks the conditions and then redirects to messages).

Comment: @serg even if it causes the error, my code works all fine. Can I ignore it safely or will it be an issue down the line?

Answer (score 0):

placing the redirection piece of code inside the success function

```
success: function (result) {
    //alert('startline posted');
},
```

of the AJAX POST method solved a similar issue which I was facing.